# Envio de mail con archivo adjunto - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando que cuando se cree un registro envie un correo con un archivo adjunto. 
Este archivo adjunto esta en el directorio publico del proyecto (public/registers_img)

```
public function build()
{
    $this->subject('Correo de notificación');
    return $this->markdown('Mails.newRegister')
        ->with(['employeeName' => $this->name, 'Date'=>$this->date, 'Note'=>$this->note])
        ->attachFromStorage(public_path('registers_img'.$this->file));
}
```

Al enviar el correo me sale este error

```
{message: "C:\xampp\htdocs\GMacro\public\registers_img\2018-11-06_Global_Test.png",…}
exception: "Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado

En lugar de

```
 ->attachFromStorage(public_path('registers_img\\'.$this->file));
```

Utilice

```
->attach(public_path('registers_img\\'.$this->file));
```